# How to Dynamically Populate Slider and Get Value

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a slider declared in XAML that I want to populate with values depending on a certain selection by the user. A page is populated dynamically with several UserControl items called PhotoThumbnail which contain several properties. Once determining which PhotoThumbnail was chosen I want to show a slider to the user to adjust some properties. I have declared a single slider in XAML, and I am trying to use this same slider repeatedly. Based on a user's selection the slider will be populated with different minimum and maximum values, and its final value the user selects will be applied to certain settings of the properties. To illustrate this I have the following

XAML

```
<Slider x:Name="sl" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

XAML.CS

```
void EditableEllipse_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender != null)
        {
            DependencyObject tappedElement = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;
            // find parent UI element of type PhotoThumbnail
            PhotoThumbnail i = this.FindParentOfType<PhotoThumbnail>(tappedElement);
            if (i != null)
            {
                BuildControl(i);
            }

            p.IsOpen = true;
            FilterPagePivot.IsHitTestVisible = false;
        }
    }

    private void BuildControl(PhotoThumbnail p)
    {
        switch(p.NName)
        {
            case "1":
                sl = new Slider
                {
                    Minimum = 1,
                    Maximum = 256,
                    Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible
                };
                break;
            case "2":
                 sl = new Slider
                {
                    Minimum = 1,
                    Maximum = 10,
                    Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible
                };
                break;
              ...
        }
    }
```

Mainly, the slider in XAML does not take on the newly defined properties, and also is not visible. To note I am capturing the changes in the ValueChanged event of the slider as they occur.

Comment: Why not just make all this stuff into an itemstemplate for one of the itemscontrol based controls like itemscontrol, listbox, gridview, whatever...? Sounds much easier than this route.

Comment: Would you mind explaining in further detail? The way my View is set up is I have a WrapPanel that is dynamicaly populated within the Loaded event with the PhotoThumbnail items. This is within a PivotItem. Under the Pivot, but within the same Grid I have defined a Popup containing the Slider, and once a user selects an item I want to populate the ListPicker based on the item select and allow the user to use the slider to change a setting which is unique to each ThumbnailItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted code creates new instances of the Slider -- you should use the existing Slider instance instead, ie:

```
 switch(p.NName)
    {
        case "1":
            sl.Minimum = 1;
            sl.Maximum = 256;
            sl.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            break;
```

Note: I believe you should treat the generated XAML members (the ones you reference by their `x:Name` attribute like "sl") as read-only.

Comment: This worked great, but I am having issues with populating the Slider the first time around. The default values are being used and setting the slider properties never executes in code, and jumps straight to ValueChanged event. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829593/slider-not-dynamically-created-properly